# best and worst case

Tags: algorithm

I need help to find best case and worst case of this code with explanation. I think worst case is O(n).

```
public static boolean adjacentDuplicates(int[] a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++)
    if (a[i] == a[i+1]) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That’s right. Now what’s the fastest it can return, and how does that change with the length of `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case is in the first comparison `return` the value. Hence, if `a[0] == a[1]` the time complexity is `\Theta(1)`. And the worse is the comparison will not be satisfied up to the end of the loop. Hence, the worst-case complexity is `\Theta(n)` (that `n` is the length of the input array `a`).